# Use ajax variable in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm getting some value from mysql by using ajax.

But i cant use it in HighCharts.

Shortly like this:

```
 var Name;
(function riza() {
        $.ajax({
            url: './riza.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                Name = Number(result['Name']);
                setTimeout(riza, refresh);
                //...some code here
                alert(Name); //FIRST ALERT
            }
        });
    }());

(function test(){
    alert(Name);  //SECOND ALERT
    setTimeout(test,1000);
}());

    $(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });
            new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        style: {...},
                        events: {...}
                    },
                    title: {...},
                    xAxis: {...},
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'A'+ Name //I WANT USE IT HERE
                        },
                    series: [{...},{...}]
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

FIRST ALERT show "Hospital". 
This is true and i want it.

SECOND ALERT show "Undefined" than after interval show "Hospital".

So i cant use it in highcharts. I think HighCharts must wait ajax.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
function riza() {
var Name;
    $.ajax({
        url: './riza.php',
        type: 'POST',

        async:false,

        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            Name = Number(result['Name']);
            setTimeout(riza, refresh);
            //...some code here
            alert(Name); //FIRST ALERT
        }
    });

  return Name;
}//end function

(function test(){
Name = riza();
alert(Name);  //SECOND ALERT
setTimeout(test,1000);
}());
```

Comment: I just put `async: false` and everythings is work fine :). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(function(){
   var name = "your initial value"
   getHighcharts(name);
});
```

in ajax success call function

```
$.ajax({
        url: './riza.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            Name = Number(result['Name']);
            setTimeout(riza, refresh);
            //...some code here
            alert(Name); //FIRST ALERT

            getHighcharts(Name);

        }
    });



function getHighcharts(name){
    // your Highcharts code with passed name
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. just `async: false` work fine me.